# YOLOv5 only detects when changing video resolution

Tags: opencv, pytorch, resolution, yolov5

I'm using YOLOv5 to detect persons in a video, which has a 944x1080 resolution. I'm using OBS-studio to stream the video as a virtual webcam. This is for testing purposes, but with the idea of using real cameras already installed from clients.

There's no custom code involved, just vanilla YOLO. The model is the YOLO's default `yolov5s.pt`.

YOLO fails at detecting any person unless I change the resolution of the video to 1280x720 (or similar), then detects very well.

My command is simple

```
$ python3 detect.py --nosave --source 2 --classes 0
```

Is there any way to change the resolution of the frames before performing a detection, so to normalize the resolution of possible different cameras?

Comment: Maybe the object detection model was trained with a specific resolution? Maybe you are not pre-processing the frames before sending them to the CNN? Who knows? Without any of your code we can only speculate.

Comment: @stateMachine there's no custom code, it's just vanilla installed yolo. I was messing with [detect.py](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/detect.py), but I'm fairly new in the subject and still can't get the right steps. The model is the yolo's default `yolov5s.pt`.

Comment: You might want to check that yolo is not resizing your images: [see here](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov3/issues/232)

Comment: everyone resizes their pictures and doesn't care about **stretching** the contents. the network might be confused because you give it weirdly stretched data. **crop or pad** instead. a circle (in the scene) has to look like a circle to the network, not like an egg.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz They are no pictures, but camera stream, which I don't have control of.

Comment: then you need to get control of the code of `detect.py`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz *"or the code of detect.py"* that' what I'm aming for (and doing), but I'm still not sure how to do it, that's why my question is maybe  not specific enough. I was hoping to get a clue from this post about where to start (pytoch?).

Comment: I'd suggest opening that file and looking for anything that says "resize"

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz In fact I got to resize with `opencv`, but seemingly in the wrong line or the wrong variable. The output changes to 1280x720, but no detection is made. I think I have to work with a varaible (`im = torch.from_numpy(im).to(device)`) but as I'm still learning the subject I'm not sure. I'll continue investigating.

Answer (score 0):

In [detect.py](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/detect.py) you have to resize the tensor with `pytorch`:

```py
from torchvision.transforms import Resize as rs

        im = torch.from_numpy(im).to(device) # line 119

        r = rs((736, 1280))
        im = r(im)
```

Then to be displayed correctly usin `opencv`:

```py
            imc = im0.copy() if save_crop else im0  # line 164
            im0 = cv2.resize(im0.copy(), (1280,736))
```